# Замена цикла for in range на while python

Tags: python, while

Скажите, пожалуйста, как заменить цикл `for in range` на `while`?

```
def what (a, b):

    res = a
    for i in range(b):
        res = res + 1

    return res
```

Comment: Либо этот пример просто для понимания, как заменять один цикл на другой, либо я не понимаю, зачем тут цикл, если это просто функция суммы двух чисел, но выполненная через цикл

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```
def what (a, b):

    res = a
    while b:
        res = res + 1
        b -= 1

    return res
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
def what(a, b):
  res = a
  i = 0
  while i < b:
    res += 1
    i +=1
  return res
```

Comment: спасибо большое